# Ejecutar if cuando mi actividad no está en pantalla (Android)

Tags: android

Buenas, estoy creando una aplicación en Android y he sobrescrito el método onBackPressed de la siguiente forma:

```
public void onBackPressed(){
    if(isAct){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else{
        finish();
    }
}
```

De esta forma, cuando presiono el botón atrás, mi aplicación va a la pantalla principal y sigue ejecutándose. En dicha ejecución además tengo una condición if:

```
if(dist1<dist2 && isAct == true){
        isAct = false;
        Intent actSuena = new Intent(this, suena.class);
        startActivity(actSuena);
    }
```

Mi problema es que si se dan las condiciones del if, el código de dicho if no se ejecuta hasta que vuelvo a la aplicación. Me gustaría saber cómo hacer para que el código del if se ejecute aunque esté en la pantalla principal o en otra aplicación distinta.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien lo que quieres realizar, pero si de una activity A llamas una activity B al pulsar atras se vueleve a A sin problema, en caso que quieras eliminar una activity de la pila usar finish()

Answer (score 0):

Ese código solo se va a ejecutar si la pantalla esta corriendo. Lo ideal es que lo hagas en un servicio.

Lo único que debes hacer es ejecutar el servicio y este correrá en segundo plano

```
  public class HelloIntentService extends IntentService {

  public HelloIntentService() {
      super("HelloIntentService");
  }


  @Override
  protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
     //aqui va tu codigo
  }
}
```